# How can I right trim a string with sed - and not kill the string if the pattern is not there?

Tags: sed, zsh

I am writing a function in `zsh` which has a string

```
"find . -a -print:10"
```

the `:10` part needs to be trimmed off the right. This might change in the future to become `:23` or `:77` etc so it seems a pattern like `:[0-9]+` is needed.

also, the string might have the form

```
find . -a -print
```

In which case if there is no `:[0-9]+` pattern on the end, then the string should be left unchanged.

so

- `find . -a -print:10` should become `find . -a -print`
  and
- `find . -a -print` should stay as `find . -a -print`

#### What I have tried so far

```
% sed -nr 's/(.*)(:[0-9]+)?/\1/p' <<<'find . -a -print:10'
find . -a -print:10     # ':10' not getting trimmed
```

If I try

```
sed -nr 's/(.*)(:[0-9]+)/\1/p' <<<'find . -a -print:10'
find . -a -print  # ':10' getting trimmed GOOD ✔✔
```

but the same `sed` expression

```
 sed -nr 's/(.*)(:[0-9]+)/\1/p' <<<'find . -a -print'
 # no output
```

How can I right trim this string?

Comment: Why would you want to use sed for this - rather than your shell's own parameter expansion capabilities (e.g. `"${str%:*}"`)?

Comment: *"How can I right trim a string with sed - and not kill the string if the pattern is not there?"* — `sed` doesn't kill any lines unless you tell it to.

Comment: at steeldriver good question, I was going to address that, but didn't want the question to be too long. its because `*` globs match too many characters, i.e. if the string became `find -iname "foo\:bar.txt"` then the glob '*' in  `"${str%:*}"` would match `bar.txt` . Im sure `zsh` has some fancier globbing (extended globs) but I'm not experienced with them.

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of [Shell test to find a pattern in a string](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/192887) because basically that's what you want: test if your `string` matches the regex `:[0-9]+$` (and if it does update `string` value to `${string%:*}`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using `-n` if you don't want to suppress the default output?

Just use:

```
sed -E -e 's/:[0-9]+$//'
```

Comment: I'm using `-n` with the `s///p` flag, so I want to suppress automatic pattern space printing, but explicitly print substitutions

Comment: @the_velour_fog, right, but you *also* want to print if there was *no* substitution.  That's literally the meaning of the title of your question.

Comment: Yes your right, I was totally going at in the wrong way, this is of course what I should have done the in beginning... thanks :)

Comment: @the_velour_fog :)