# Test if a string contains a substring

Tags: shell-script, variable, string, control-flow

I have the code

```
file="JetConst_reco_allconst_4j2t.png"
if [[ $file == *_gen_* ]];
then
    echo "True"
else
    echo "False"
fi
```

I test if `file` contains "gen". The output is "False". Nice!

The problem is when I substitute "gen" with a variable `testseq`:

```
file="JetConst_reco_allconst_4j2t.png"
testseq="gen"
if [[ $file == *_$testseq_* ]];
then
    echo "True"
else
    echo "False"
fi
```

Now the output is "True". How could it be? How to fix the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shell test to find a pattern in a string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192887/shell-test-to-find-a-pattern-in-a-string)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to interpolate the `$testseq` variable with one of the following ways:

- `$file == *_"$testseq"_*` (here `$testseq` considered as a fixed string)
- `$file == *_${testseq}_*` (here `$testseq` considered as a pattern).

Or the `_` immediately after the variable's name will be taken as part of the variable's name (it's a valid character in a variable name).

Comment: Correct answer as it applies to OP, but w/o being portable. (This is no criticism of the provided answer, just a warning to readers).  ;-)

Comment: what's a portable way?

Answer (score 39):

Use the `=~` operator to make regular expression comparisons:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="JetConst_reco_allconst_4j2t.png"
testseq="gen"
if [[ $file =~ $testseq ]];
then
    echo "True"
else
    echo "False"
fi
```

This way, it will compare if `$file` has `$testseq` on its contents.

```
user@host:~$ ./string.sh
False
```

If I change `testseq="Const"`:

```
user@host:~$ ./string.sh
True
```

But, be careful with what you feed `$testseq` with. If the string on it somehow represents a regex (like `[0-9]` for example), there is a higher chance to trigger a "match".

**Reference**:

- [Advanced Bash Script guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver3.html#REGEXMATCHREF)

Comment: It looks like this answer is for "bash" only

Answer (score 24):

```
file="JetConst_reco_allconst_4j2t.png"
testseq="gen"

case "$file" in
    *_"$testseq"_*) echo 'True'  ;;
    *)              echo 'False'
esac
```

Using `case ... esac` is one of the simplest ways to perform a pattern match in a portable way. It works as a "switch" statement in other languages (`bash`, `zsh`, and `ksh93` also allows you to do *fall-through* in various incompatible ways). The patterns used are the standard file name globbing patterns.

The issue you are having is due to the fact that `_` is a valid character in a variable name. The shell will thus see `*_$testseq_*` as "`*_` followed by the value of the variable `$testseq_` and an `*`". The variable `$testseq_` is undefined, so it will be expanded to an empty string, and you end up with `*_*`, which obviously matches the `$file` value that you have. You may expect to get `True` as long as the filename in `$file` contains at least one underscore.

To properly delimit the name of the variable, use `"..."` around the expansion: `*_"$testseq"_*`.  This would use the value of the variable as a string.  Would you want to use the value of the variable as a *pattern*, use `*_${testseq}_*` instead.

Another quick fix is to include the underscores in the value of `$testseq`:

```
testseq="_gen_"
```

and then just use `*"$testseq"*` as the pattern (for a string comparison).

Comment: So the shell will be looking for a variable $testseq_ and not find it and substitute it with an empty string.

Comment: @Viesturs That's is the heart of the issue, yes.

Comment: For a substring search it should be `*"$testseq"*` for `case` like for `[[...]]` (except for zsh unless you enable globsubst)

Comment: Simpler than `[ "${str##*substr*}" ] || echo True` ?

Comment: @Isaac In terms of reading and understanding what's happening, yes. It's also easy to extend one test with more test cases without getting an "if-then-elif-then-elif" spaghetti. Although testing a single string the way you show (whether a string disappears in a substitution) _is_ shorter.

Answer (score 6):

For the portable way to test if an string contains a substring, use:

```
file="JetConst_reco_allconst_4j2t.png";       testseq="gen"

[ "${file##*$testseq*}" ] || echo True Substring is present
```

Or `"${file##*"$testseq"*}"` to avoid interpreting glob characters in `testseq`.

Comment: You'd need something like [ "${file##*$testseq*}" != "$file" ] because in dash that is Remove Largest Prefix Pattern.

Comment: No, @NoelGrandin there is no change on most shells (including dash), the **Largest Prefix Pattern** will be the whole string if the variable subpattern (`$testseq`) value is contained inside the `$file` value. Try: `dash -c 'file="JetConst_reco_allconst_4j2t.png"; testseq="reco"; echo "=${file##*"$testseq"*}="'` to confirm that dash will remove the whole string.